# xsane cannot find my scanner

Tags: 14.04, scanner, epson

On Ubuntu 14.04, just installed xsane .0998, and it cannot find my device, EPSON Perfection V330 Photo. The device has been connected and powered on. What can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have everything else set up properly (firewalls, drivers, etc) you could try installing [the daily sane ppa](https://launchpad.net/~rolfbensch/+archive/ubuntu/sane-git).  This got a Canon Maxify working for us when nothing else did.

Comment: Tried to install. got message:

Comment: Got message  W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/rolfbensch/sane-git/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'd/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

Comment: That message ,means you made a mistake when adding the ppa.

Comment: This time ppa installed without error messages but still "no scanners detected".

Comment: I tried connecting the scanner to different USB ports of the computer, or not connecting to any, running with the device turned on or off, but the result was still the same (no scanners detected), and here is something from the system log:  gregory@gregory-MS-7850:~$ grep simple-scan /var/log/syslog
Jul 14 09:41:43 gregory-MS-7850 simple-scan: io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1
Jul 14 18:39:19 gregory-MS-7850 simple-scan: io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1
Jul 14 18:43:47 gregory-MS-7850 simple-scan: io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1

Comment: Tried to use a different application to access the scanner, no help. @OrganicMarble